# Can libclang tell me if a function has weak linkage?

Tags: c++, c, clang

I am using the **libclang** C interface to **Clang**, and trying to figure out if the function definition at my current **CXCursor** has weak linkage, i.e. was declared with `_attribute__((weak))`

`clang_Cursor_hasAttrs(cursor)` tells me that the function with weak linkage does indeed have one or more attributes,  but doesn't tell me which ones.

I have been looking through the documentation of libclang at https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__MANIP.html  and also at the header file `clang-c/Index.h` but cannot find any function to extract this information.

Is there a way to do this in the C interface,  or do I need to use the underlying C++ interface of Clang to achieve this?

Comment: according to wikipedia:

 `nm | grep someObjectFile` should output `a weak function symbol is marked with "W" if a weak default definition is available, and with "w" if it is not` if it is marked with a U that would be external linkage... and T would be standard default linkage

Comment: `nm` works on an object files, libclang on source and its AST ...

Comment: well I didn't put in an answer... I just made a comment on how you can figure that out.